# Vector of sf::RenderWIndows

Tags: c++, c++14, sfml

I have a program that needs multiple sfml windows open and I am trying to have a function that emplaces back windows to an array. I have the vector made out of unique_ptr but when I go to use emplace_back I get this error.

```
Error C2664 'sf::RenderWindow::RenderWindow(const sf::RenderWindow &)': cannot convert argument 1 from '_Ty' to 'sf::WindowHandle'  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.25.28610\include\memory  2064
```

Minimum code that produces error:

```cpp
void MakeKey::DrawKey(string input)
{
    unique_ptr <sf::RenderWindow> window = make_unique<sf::RenderWindow>(new sf::RenderWindow);
    MakeKey::NewKey Key;
    if (input == "A")
        Key.Img.loadFromFile("Assets/Images/A.png");
    else if (input == "D")
        Key.Img.loadFromFile("Assets/Images/D.png");
    //ect
    window->create(sf::VideoMode(Key.Img.getSize().x, Key.Img.getSize().y, 32), "Key", sf::Style::None);
    unique_ptr<sf::RenderWindow> windowPtr;
    WindowArray.emplace_back(move(windowPtr));
    Key.Tex.loadFromImage(Key.Img);
    Key.Sprite.setTexture(Key.Tex);
    KeyArray.emplace_back(move(Key));
    WindowArray.emplace_back(move(window));
    cout << "KeyArray Has " << KeyArray.size() << " Elements\n" << "WindowArray Has " << WindowArray.size() << " Elements" << endl;
}
```

```cpp
    vector <MakeKey::NewKey> KeyArray;
    vector <unique_ptr<sf::RenderWindow>> WindowArray;
```

for reference RenderWindow is noncopyable.
I have never used unique pointers before so that is likely the issue. Anyway thank you for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
unique_ptr <sf::RenderWindow> window = make_unique<sf::RenderWindow>(new sf::RenderWindow);
```

should be

```
unique_ptr <sf::RenderWindow> window = make_unique<sf::RenderWindow>();
```

The arguments to `make_unique` are the arguments you want to give to the constructor of `sf::RenderWindow`.

You are getting mixed up with this notation

```
unique_ptr <sf::RenderWindow> window(new sf::RenderWindow>());
```

which is an alternative to `make_unqiue` but generally `make_unique` is preferred on grounds of simplicity and efficiency.

Also don't forget you can simplify further by using auto

```
auto window = make_unique<sf::RenderWindow>();
```

Comment: ok thank you. Sorry that was probably something I should have figured out on my own.